# Popup image from text

Tags: read-more

I'm a newbie and I've been trying to figure out how can I get an image popup from a read more button. I've done this:

```
<p class="p1">
  <a class="btn right ngg-fancybox" href="http://www.travelistamarketing.com/Samples/Santorini_Sample.jpg" rel="999" data-src="http://www.travelistamarketing.com/Samples/Santorini_Sample.jpg" data-thumbnail="http://www.travelistamarketing.com/Samples/Santorini_Sample.jpg">READ MORE</a>
</p>
```

But it doesn't work properly - the image isn't the correct size.  Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with "READ MORE".

Comment: You need to show some code, are you using JavaScript or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then you can try the code bellow:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Popup image</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="//placehold.it/1000x600" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```